# How can I keep the dock over other applications?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, appmenu, dock, dash-to-dock

Disclaimer: Super new Ubuntu user here!

Is there a setting to enable or a way to keep the dock over an application instead of it appearing under an application or hiding when an application is fully maximized? Have been trying to find a way to do so with either Ubuntu dock and Dash to dock. Open to other dock suggestions.

Dock appearing below firefox

[image]

Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS